# Allow us to create question DRAFTS even if we are Q-banned or "Have a history of asking low quality questions"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, asking-questions, post-ban, draft

But make sure to tell us that we can't post it, so we won't waste time. This "history of asking low quality questions" thing is to apparently "help" us put more time and effort into our questions. But why not allow us to create a question draft, so we can make progress on a good question and post it once the ban ends. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: Why not just create a draft in your favorite text editor? If this were to happen, I guarantee we'd get a lot of people who wouldn't read the text saying they can't post it and then complain about having their time wasted anyway.

Comment: I would prefer that Q-banned users get used to not having any access to the site at all, to force them to learn how to resolve their technical questions *without any* use of SO, to reduce their dependence. The majority of Q-bans are applied to users who have cultivated an over-dependence on SO or other people in general to solve their problems for them. The ban is intended, in part, to show the effectiveness of *self*-reliance. Plus: during the ban, you’re only going to get 2 new Qs per year. What’s the good of stacking them up? Are you going to have the same question 6 months from now?

Comment: Focus on getting out of the ban by editing your questions. Make progress on the problem itself.

Comment: @RobertLongson I did. I had 2 of them undeleted and edited.

Comment: You can use the [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). Save to a local `.txt` after you are done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one draft can be created at a time, and Stack Overflow does not provide a very reliable system for saving or managing drafts anyway. I suggest keeping this information in some other way, such as a text file on your computer or using an in-browser Markdown editor, such as [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).

Aside from that, I really don't see the point in taking developer time to build additional tools/features for users who are banned from asking questions due to a chronic history of low-quality contributions.